# Passing label value from HTML to TS

Tags: html, angular, typescript, filter, label

I have a code that goes something like this :

```
<sh-toggle label='ABCD' id = 'ABCD'> </sh-toggle>
```

I want to extract the value of label in TS file. Please tell me how it can be done? If i am trying document.getElementByID('ABCD'), then i am getting whole toggle component and unable to filter label from there.

Please mind sh-toggle is a custom tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `viewchild` query to fetch a child component.

Create a template reference variable(`#el`) for the component / element you want to query.

```
<sh-toggle label='ABCD' id='ABCD' #el></sh-toggle>
```

Use `viewchild` query to fetch the child component. It looks for the first element that matches the selector.

```
@ViewChild('el', { read: ElementRef }) el: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
   console.log('label', this.el.nativeElement.getAttribute('label'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If sh-toggle is your own directive (e.g.: ToggleDirective) then you can access its properties by @ViewChild:

1. considering you have a label @Input within ToggleDirective
2. add  @ViewChild(ToggleDirective) toggle:ToggleDirective;
3. then simply anywhere from .ts just toggle.label

This is an angular way to access a component property.

document.getElementByID is never the angular way.

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-e93ejz?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if you are using any frameworks/libraries on the UI side.
Just see if this code is enough

```
document.getElementById("ABCD").attributes.getNamedItem("label").value
```